# EurekaServer created by STS not starting

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I'm new to Spring cloud, going through some videos I have created EurekaServer from STS , and tried to run as spring-boot application.

Is anything from below which I need to do?

1. configure anything for making Euraka server run?
2. before running Euraka server, do I need some other services up and running?
3. add any properties in application.properties at resources folder?

My application.properties is empty as of now and I am getting the following error.

```
2018-07-10 01:31:11.109  INFO 13760 --- [           main] 
ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-07-10 01:31:11.125 ERROR 13760 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sc.eurakaserver.EurakaServerApplication.main(EurakaServerApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:413) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webMvcMetricsFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/web/servlet/WebMvcMetricsAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'webMvcMetricsFilter' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'simpleMeterRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/export/simple/SimpleMetricsExportAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Lists
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:732) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:474) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1256) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:226) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:214) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:91) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:80) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:250) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:237) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:54) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5245) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'simpleMeterRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/export/simple/SimpleMetricsExportAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Lists
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:589) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Lists
    at com.netflix.config.PropertyWrapper.<init>(PropertyWrapper.java:41) ~[archaius-core-0.7.6.jar:0.7.6]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.properties.archaius.HystrixDynamicPropertiesArchaius$ArchaiusDynamicProperty.<init>(HystrixDynamicPropertiesArchaius.java:62) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.properties.archaius.HystrixDynamicPropertiesArchaius$StringDynamicProperty.<init>(HystrixDynamicPropertiesArchaius.java:73) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.properties.archaius.HystrixDynamicPropertiesArchaius.getString(HystrixDynamicPropertiesArchaius.java:34) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.HystrixPlugins.getPluginImplementationViaProperties(HystrixPlugins.java:344) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.HystrixPlugins.getPluginImplementation(HystrixPlugins.java:334) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.HystrixPlugins.getEventNotifier(HystrixPlugins.java:129) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.hystrix.HystrixMetricsBinder.bindTo(HystrixMetricsBinder.java:35) ~[micrometer-core-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MeterRegistryConfigurer.lambda$addBinders$1(MeterRegistryConfigurer.java:83) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MeterRegistryConfigurer.addBinders(MeterRegistryConfigurer.java:83) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MeterRegistryConfigurer.configure(MeterRegistryConfigurer.java:65) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MeterRegistryPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(MeterRegistryPostProcessor.java:51) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:439) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1712) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Lists
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    ... 50 common frames omitted
```

My Pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.sc.eurakaserver</groupId>
<artifactId>EurakaServer</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>EurakaServer</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<!--    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

```
package com.sc.eurakaserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurakaServerApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(EurakaServerApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

Can any one please help identify what I'm missing?

Comment: seems to be missing transitive dependency have you installed with maven?

Comment: yes i have cleaned , installed and updated

Comment: https://pastiebin.com/5b4438e3059eb

Comment: You found any solution for this? I am also facing similar problem now.

Comment: @amyst i didnt find any solution. i followed another tutorial, https://o7planning.org/en/11267/spring-boot-tutorial-for-beginners

Answer (score 0):

> 1. configure anything for making Eureka server run?

No, if you just include eureka server dependency from STS starter project, that is all that is "required" to create sample starter.

> 2. before running Eureka server, do I need some other services up and running?

No, it is not necessary to have any service to be registering with eureka server.

> 3. add any properties in application.properties at resources folder?

This is little complicated. Theoretically, no, it is not required to add any properties, but due to inclusion of eureka-server dependency and @EnableEurekaServer, it will try to register with eureka server, which will throw a runtime exception, but not stop/teminate your application. To solve this you can add

```
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
```

Beside this if you are running multiple spring boot application from your local machine, then it is advised to add

```
server.port=<your port like 8080, 8081 etc>
```

Coming to your exception you faced, I tried following exact steps as you suggested, but I didn't get any exception while starting the app.

So here is my guess on what could have caused

1. You had another application running on the same port at that time - i.e port 8080 (which is default port)
2. I have seen the exception in your trace for some cases where app is being configured to run in google cloud app engine, not sure if that's what was being tried.

I have created a sample vanilla eureka server project, hope it helps you 
[sample eureka server](https://github.com/vyomrastogi/se-ts-eurekaserver)

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving below code in yml file or use same properties. Other than this all looks good to me.

```
server:
  port: {port_number}
spring:
  profiles: default
  application:
    name: eureka-server.com
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: eureka-server.com
    appname: eureka-cluster
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://${spring.application.name}:${server.port}/eureka/
logging:
  level:
    com:
      netflix:
        eureka: OFF
        discovery: OFF
```